# Trace of a bilinear Form

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

What's the definition of trace of a $(m,n)$-Tensor $T:\underbrace{V\times \cdots \times V}_{k- \text{times}}\times\underbrace{V^*\times\cdots V^*}_{l-\text{times}}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that $\{\mathrm{e}_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is any orthonormal basis of real vector space $V$ with inner product $< , >$?

Comment: You say $B$ is a bilinear form, but the domain suggests that $B$ has $k+l$ arguments. Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: That's because this question has been massively edited.  Maybe you should rollback and just put out a new question about tensors.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer for the case of $k+l=2$, tensors that can act as bilinear forms.

Let $v\in V$ and $\alpha\in V^*$. Consider a simple (1,1) tensor  $v \otimes \alpha \in V\otimes V^*$. It can be used as a bilinear map $(V^* \times V)\to K$, $(f,e)\mapsto f(v) \cdot \alpha(e)$. Its matrix in the given basis (and the dual basis) is $[v^i][\alpha_j]$ (a column times a row).

The trace, or contraction map, for this tensor, is defined to be the duality pairing, the evaluation map of its constituents: $\operatorname{tr}(v \otimes \alpha)=\alpha(v)$, or in coordinates, $\sum \alpha_i v^i.$

Similarly, for a (2,0) tensor $u\otimes v$ with the matrix $[u][v]^T$, we could define $\operatorname{tr}(u\otimes v)=\langle u, v\rangle$, or using coordinates, $\sum u_iv_i.$